# Managesieve Rouncube no connect to the server

Tags: dovecot, roundcube, sieve

I had a Dovecot and Roundcube server installed on the same machine, and Managesieve worked fine.

But I changed Rouncube to another server and I can't get managesieve to connect.

I already modified the managesieve configuration file indicating the IP of the Dovecot server, but in the rouncube log I see that it tries to connect to localhost, I don't understand...

Unable to connect to managesieve on localhost:4190 in /var/wwwebmail/html/plugins/managesieve/lib/Roundcube/rcube_sieve_engine.php on line 223

Comment: "modified the managesieve configuration file"? Did you possible modify the distributor-provided configuration file template (`plugins/managesieve/config.inc.php.dist`) instead of your actual configuration (`plugins/managesieve/config.inc.php`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved....
I configured the host with the IP of my Dovecot server and it still didn't work, but I noticed that my PHP-FPM server was caching the initial configuration of the PHP files, so restarting the PHP-FPM service reloaded the configuration and it worked fine now.